# strongSwan - how do i generate pre shared keys?

Tags: ipsec, private-key, strongswan

I'm using the [strongswan documentation right here](http://www.strongswan.org/docs/readme4.htm#section_2.5)

I've added to `/etc/ipsec.secrets` the following line:

```
: RSA moonKey.pem "SomePwd"
```

however i don't know how to create `moonKey.pem`. Any ideas?

this is a follow up question to this one:
[strongSwan ipsec setup, couple of questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/257970/strongswan-ipsec-setup-couple-of-questions)

Comment: I would appreciate if someone with enough rep could edit the post and add a "strongSwan" tag. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://lists.strongswan.org/pipermail/users/2009-May/003431.html) on the strongSwan mailing list seems to cover your question.

Gist:

```
openssl req -x509 -days 1460 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout moonKey.pem -out mooncert.pem -subj "/CN=moon/" -nodes
```

Comment: Note: they don't tell you this in the guide because they assume (based on [text here](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Fornewbies) ) that you know this:  _"Also, we consider that you know how to use and generate SSH public and private key pairs and that you know how to connect remotely to a host using SSH."_

Comment: thats for creating moonCert.pem. moonKey.pem is supposedly the shared secret file between the hosts

Comment: See: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#item__keyout

Comment: so according to this scheme, at what point is used the shared secret? i don't see in the documentation any mention of copy the same file on the sun and moon gateways

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to generate pre-shared keys and not use certificates, then two examples are provided at [Linux Kernel 2.6 using KAME-tools](http://www.ipsec-howto.org/x299.html) using xxd -- "make a hexdump or do the reverse"

```
$ # Generate 128 Bit long key
$ #
$ dd if=/dev/random count=16 bs=1 | xxd -ps
16+0 Records ein
16+0 Records aus
cd0456eff95c5529ea9e918043e19cbe

$ # Generate 192 Bit long key
$ #
$ dd if=/dev/random count=24 bs=1 | xxd -ps
24+0 Records ein
24+0 Records aus
9d6c4a8275ab12fbfdcaf01f0ba9dcfb5f424c878e97f888ode
```